# Download a file to a base64 string

Tags: node.js, request

I'm running Node.js code on a readonly file system and I would like to download a file and convert this file directly to a base64 string but without writing the file on the disk.

Now I have the following:

```
let file = fs.createWriteStream(`file.jpg`);
request({
    uri: fileUrl
  })
  .pipe(file).on('finish', () => {
    let buff = fs.readFileSync(file);
    let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
})
```

But this solution is writing on the disk so this is not possible for me.

I would like to do the same but without the need of the temp file on the disk. Is it possible?

Comment: See [base64-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-stream).

Comment: tx @jfriend00 seems to be what I need, but how to "pipe" into a variable? I need to retrieve the base64 as string. I don't find a lot of exemples. Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `pipe()` into a variable.  You collect the data off the stream into a variable as the data arrives.  I think you can do something like this:

```
const Base64Encode = require('base64-stream').Base64Encode;
const request = require('request');

let base64Data = "";
request({
    uri: fileUrl
}).pipe(new Base64Encode()).on('data', data => {
    base64Data += data;
}).on('finish', () => {
    console.log(base64Data);
}).on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```